# Emacs/realgud/Python: How to display variables at each step?

Tags: python, debugging, realgud

Using emacs and realgud one can have a separate buffer that automatically shows where the program is currently stopped (by displaying that line of source code).

Is there an easy way to get realgud to display a list of variables/expressions (hopefully in a separate window) when the debugger stops?

Comment: It's open source, so feel free to add something. For the trepan2 and trepan3 python debuggers the command is called `info locals`